# SFDX force:user:list : meaning of output fields

Tags: salesforcedx, oauth

When I issue the command
`sfdx force:user:list --targetusername user@example.com --json`

I get the response:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": [
    {
      "defaultMarker": "(A)",
      "alias": "",
      "username": "user@example.com",
      "profileName": "System Administrator",
      "orgId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "accessToken": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxlongaccesstokenxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "instanceUrl": "https://an-instance-url.my.salesforce.com",
      "loginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
      "userId": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    },{
       ...other users...
    }
}
```

The response above includes an Access Token but I cannot use it with OAuth to make requests.

But when I do this command: `sfdx force:user:display -u user@example.com` the response includes an Access Token which can be used in OAuth headers to make requests.

Since the actual access token is included in the response to force:user:display, what is the purpose of the access token included in the response to force:user:list? I notice it is different, and does not work with OAuth. I cannot find any mention of it in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the definition of access token output parameter provided by these commands' outputs, but the access token you get via the command `sfdx force:user:list --targetusername user@example.com --json` is **encrypted (for security reasons)**. I couldn't find any official documentation to support the above statement. Also, I believe this encrypted token cannot be used directly in the HTTP request's Authorization header. Note that when you create a scratch org or authorize a user to an org, a `<username.json>` file is created in the root directory's `.sfdx` folder. In this user info JSON file, you can observe the same encrypted access token (along with an encrypted refresh token). I guess `sfdx force:user:list` simply lists out the access token from these files. While it might seem that this encrypted value is not really useful to you, it is indeed essential (along with refresh token) for Salesforce CLI to get through the Authorization flow and to be able to run all the SFDX CLI commands. Access tokens expire after a specific time interval and the refresh token will be used by CLI to get a new access token. You can observe this by running `sfdx force:user:list` & `sfdx force:user:display` after few hours (or a day) and check that the access token will have changed.

Try removing the encrypted access and refresh token from the `<username.json>` file, you will find that both `sfdx force:user:list` & `sfdx force:user:display` will return missing access token error. This shows that the encrypted token seen in the `<username.json>` file or `sfdx force:user:list`'s response is required for generating a valid access token (I mean the usable access token that you can get via `sfdx force:user:display` or `sfdx force:org:display`).